# Detect inhibited shutdown on D-Bus

Tags: linux, systemd, dbus

I use x86_64 Debian 9 Stretch. I run `systemd-inhibit cat` and then in another console `systemctl poweroff`. Shutdown correctly gets inhibited. According to [this doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) signal `PrepareForShutdown(false)` is supposed to be emitted, but I can't see it. I watch dbus with `dbus-monitor --system` and using a python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def handle(*args):
    print "PrepareForShutdown %s" % (args)

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)     # integrate into gobject main loop
bus = dbus.SystemBus()                 # connect to system wide dbus
bus.add_signal_receiver(               # define the signal to listen to
    handle,                            # callback function
    'PrepareForShutdown',              # signal name
    'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',  # interface
    'org.freedesktop.login1'           # bus name
)

loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

The program prints nothing. The `dbus-monitor` outputs few obscure messages (looks like smth calls ListInhibitors).

Is signal not being emited or I just can't catch it? My goal is to detect inhibited shutdown by listening D-Bus, how do I do it?

EDIT: Turned out when non-delayed inhibition is used, shutdown request just gets discarded, signal doesn't fire. But if I use delay lock via `systemd-inhibit --mode=delay --what=shutdown cat` then PrepareForShutdown signal fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is signal not being emited or I just can't catch it?

Not sure. My guess would be that systemd only emits the signal to processes which have taken a delay lock (unicast signal emission), as the [documentation page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) has some pretty dire warnings about race conditions if you listen for `PrepareForShutdown` *without* taking a delay lock first.

The way to check this would be to read the [systemd source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd).

> My goal is to detect inhibited shutdown by listening D-Bus, how do I do it?

If I run `sudo dbus-monitor --system` in one terminal, and then run `systemd-inhibit cat` in another, I see the following signal emission:

```
signal time=1543917703.712998 sender=:1.9 -> destination=(null destination) serial=1150 path=/org/freedesktop/login1; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "BlockInhibited"
         variant             string "shutdown:sleep:idle:handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch"
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

Hence you could watch for property changes on the `/org/freedesktop/login1` object exposed by service `org.freedesktop.login1`, and see when its `BlockInhibited` or `DelayInhibited` properties change. Shutdown is inhibited when either of those properties contains `shutdown`. They are documented on [the same documentation page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/):

> The `BlockInhibited` and `DelayInhibited` properties encode what types of
>   locks are currently taken. These fields are a colon separated list of
>   `shutdown`, `sleep`, `idle`, `handle-power-key`, `handle-suspend-key`,
>   `handle-hibernate-key`, `handle-lid-switch`. The list is basically the
>   union of the `What` fields of all currently active locks of the specific
>   mode.

Comment: Don't quite get second part. I need to be notified every time "power button is pressed or `systemctl poweroff` called", not when "someone installs inhibition lock".

Comment: Good point about delay locks though. When I use delay lock, I can see PrepareForShutdown(true) emitted. It is emitted only once, so I can detect only the first shutdown event, but that should be enough.